# regarding sizeof()

Tags: c++, memory

I have doubt regarding sizeof(). I know it gives the number of bytes used in an array. My question is what if the array is not defined, but it declared.

example:

```
float array[3];
int p = sizeof(array);
```

Comment: That is not C++ code, and I have no idea what you're talking about.  But `sizeof` only needs a declaration of a fully-defined type.

Comment: That's not a declaration of an array. That's a definition of a float.

Comment: Please note the difference between `float array(3);` and `float array[3];`. They're not same!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value yielded by `sizeof` depends solely on the type, not anything that happens at run time<sup>1</sup>.

That said, despite the name, `float array(3);` simply defines a *single* float, with an initial value of 3, so `int p=sizeof(array);` is equivalent to `int p = sizeof(float);`.

Edit: (to correspond to edited question): yes, `float array[3];` defines an array of 3 floats, so `int p = sizeof(array);` is equivalent to `int p = 3 * sizeof(float);`

---

<sup>1</sup> In C++. As of C99, the situation in C is somewhat different (but irrelevant to the question at hand).

Answer (score 1):

You are not declaring an array of floats when you use this code

```
 float array(3);
```

you have simple created a float variable **called** array with value 3. Your call of sizeof on this variable just returns the size of float. Had you declared it properly

```
float float_array[3];
```

and called `sizeof(float_array)` you would get the value you expect - `3*sizeof(float)`

Answer (score 1):

sizeof() does not give the number of bytes used in an array, your definition is incomplete and partially incorrect.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof says:

"sizeof( type) --returns size in bytes of the object representation of type"

Also float array[3] is the correct way to declare an array of floats with 3 elements as other people have noted.

Finally, sizeof( array) would return 12, whereas sizeof( array) would return 16 if you declared it with 4 elements, and sizeof( array) would return 40 if you declared an array of 5 doubles instead of floats, at least on my system. Of course, number of bytes used for data types may change from system to system.